# LINQ generates wrong sql query with system.data.sqlite

Tags: c#, sql, linq, sqlite, mono

I have the following model:

```
[Table(Name="word")]
public partial class Word
{
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey=true, Name="id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column(IsPrimaryKey=true, Name="language_id")]
    public int LanguageId { get; set; }

    [Column(Name="translation")]
    public string Translation { get; set; }

    [Column(Name="category")]
    public string Category { get; set; }

    [Column(Name="order")]
    public int Order { get; set; }
}
```

And the following code:

```
var connection = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=data.sqlite3");
var context = new DataContext(connection);
context.Log = Console.Out;

var test = from w1 in context.GetTable<Word> ()
           join w2 in context.GetTable<Word> () on w1.Id equals w2.Id
           select new {w1 = w1.Id, w2 =  w2.Id};

foreach (var i in test)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Word: {0} {1}", i.w1, i.w2);
}
```

And the output looks like this:

```
SELECT w1$.[id], w2$.[id]
FROM [word] AS w1$, [word] AS w2$
WHERE (w1$.[id] = w1$.[id])
-- Context: SqlServer Model: AttributedMetaModel Build: 4.0.0.0
Word: 1 1
Word: 1 1
Word: 1 2
Word: 1 2
Word: 1 3
Word: 1 3
Word: 1 4
Word: 1 4
Word: 1 5
Word: 1 5
```

What is going on? Why is the join condition different from what I have specified? Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong? For what it's worth, I'm using Mono on Mac and I've compiled system.data.sqlite for Mono as described on their website.

#### Update:

This work-around fixes the problem:

```
var test = from w1 in context.GetTable<Word> ()
           join w2 in context.GetTable<Word> () on w1.Id equals w2.Id
           where w1.Id == w2.Id
           select new {w1 = w1.Id, w2 =  w2.Id};
```

#### Update 2:

Apparently, linq 2 sql works quite bad with sqlite. The recommended solution is to use Entity Framework.

Comment: Is there a reason you are joining on the same column in the same table?

Comment: Yeah, this is by design. The idea is that I save words in different languages in the 'word' table. Words with the same meaning have the same id (but different language_ids). I want to get a word together with its translation. The query in the question is a minimal example that exhibits the problem that I'm encountering. As you can see, linq changes the join condition from `w1.id = w2.id` (in linq) to `w1.id = w1.id` (in sql). Obviously, this does not make sense. I do not understand why this happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is in the SQLite driver not being able to cope with self joins too well. I just tried the same thing in SQLServer

my table looks like this

```
Id  Language_id Translation
1   1   hello
1   2   bonjour
1   3   yo
2   1   bye
2   2   aurevoiur
2   3   laterz
```

and the output looks like this (i added the translation column to help see whats happening easier)

```
SELECT [t0].[id] AS [w1], [t0].[translation] AS [word1], [t1].[id] AS [w2], 
[t1].[translation] AS [word2]
FROM [word] AS [t0]
INNER JOIN [word] AS [t1] ON [t0].[id] = [t1].[id]
-- Context: SqlProvider(Sql2008) Model: AttributedMetaModel Build: 4.0.30319.18408

Word: 1 = hello,  1 = hello
Word: 1 = bonjour,  1 = hello
Word: 1 = yo,  1 = hello
Word: 1 = hello,  1 = bonjour
Word: 1 = bonjour,  1 = bonjour
Word: 1 = yo,  1 = bonjour
Word: 1 = hello,  1 = yo
Word: 1 = bonjour,  1 = yo
Word: 1 = yo,  1 = yo
Word: 2 = bye,  2 = bye
Word: 2 = aurevoiur,  2 = bye
Word: 2 = laterz,  2 = bye
Word: 2 = bye,  2 = aurevoiur
Word: 2 = aurevoiur,  2 = aurevoiur
Word: 2 = laterz,  2 = aurevoiur
Word: 2 = bye,  2 = laterz
Word: 2 = aurevoiur,  2 = laterz
Word: 2 = laterz,  2 = laterz
```

which still doesn't give you the set of results you are after (its giving every combination) - but at least its doing the join.

I'd advise splitting your data into two tables if possible, have the Word table - with the Id and other single columns, and have a translations table - which contains the actual translations, and foreign keys back to the word table. I suspect the sqlite driver will cope with this better.

Comment: Thanks for testing it with another sql driver! I think I'll file a bug report then. Your result set is exactly what I was expecting. You can now add a few where clauses (like `w1.language_id = 1` and `w2.language_id = 2`), that should filter out all the unneeded combinations.

Comment: Another work around (which I'll probably use for now): Add the join condition as an additional where clause. I've added an example to the question.